# Can a class have a map attribute with Class objects as keys and as values a list of objects of that class?

Tags: java, generics

I want something like this to compile:

```
public class RepositoryService {
   public Map<Class<? extends T>, List<T>> repository;

   public RepositoryService() {
      repository = new HashMap<>(); // doesn't matter which implementation
      repository.put(Integer.class, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
      repository.put(String.class, Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
   }

   public List<T> get(Class clazz) {
     return repository.get(clazz);
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Well yes, but first you'd have to make `RepositoryService` generic to define `T`... at which point, it doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a bit better by only adding to the map through an instance method on `RepositoryService` that ensures the types match.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RepositoryService {
    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> repository = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> put(Class<T> key, List<T> instances) {
        return (List<T>) repository.put(key, instances);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> key) {
        return (List<T>) repository.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService();
        repositoryService.put(Integer.class, asList(1, 2, 3));
        repositoryService.put(String.class, asList("A", "B", "C"));
        repositoryService.put(String.class, asList(1, 2, 3)); // doesn't compile
        List<Integer> integers = repositoryService.get(Integer.class);
        List<String> strings = repositoryService.get(String.class);
        List<Double> doubles = repositoryService.get(String.class); // doesn't compile
        System.out.println(integers);
        System.out.println(strings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RepositoryService {

   private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> repository;

   public RepositoryService() {
      repository = new HashMap<>();
      repository.put(Integer.class, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
      repository.put(String.class, Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
      return (List<T>) repository.get(clazz);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService();
      List<Integer> integers = repositoryService.get(Integer.class);
      List<String> strings = repositoryService.get(String.class);
      System.out.println(integers);
      System.out.println(strings);
   }
```

}

This does the trick. Of course there is no way to be sure that calling `get(Class<T>)` will return really a `List<T>` until runtime, but seems it's the class responsability to add the lists I don't think that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list of values will never be changed at run time, another thing you can do is to use enums.

```
public enum RepoEnum {

INTEGER(Integer.class,  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)),
STRING(String.class,  Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

private Class clazz;
private List values;

RepoEnum(Class clazz, List values){
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.values = values;
}

public static List get(Class clazz) {
    for (RepoEnum item : RepoEnum.values()) {
        if (item.getClazz().equals(clazz)) {
            return item.getValues();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee type-safety which gdejohn's solution does.

The other thing I don't like is your get() implementation which traverse a list to find one element. That's why we have maps, to efficiently search for an element given a key property of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quiet possible to let Java itself to maintain such a data integrity, since generic types are erased in runtime. But why not extend a `Map` class and  maintain the type constraint by your own code? Something like

```
public class Foo extends HashMap<Class, List>{

    @Override
    public List put(Class clazz, List list){
        ...
        // make sure every thing in list is of type clazz here
        return super.put(clazz, list);
    }

    @Override
    public List get(Object clazz){
        return super.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution ensures type-safety at runtime, as my solution.

Comment: @gaijinco Yes, It`s almost the same solution. I started writing before your submission but ended after that. Sorry for the duplicate